# Powershell script to get users who has edit access

Tags: powershell, edit

I need to get a PowerShell script to get all the users and their email address who have edit access.
It would be good if we can filter it to have only one selection only as there are only users who have edit access on more than one site. ( we only need them once)

I have SP 2010.

I need this to send an email to all the users who have edit access.
we don't have any third party tools to get these information.

Answer (score 1):

Below script is available in Technet. This script basically list permission for all users irrespective of their permission level. You can export this to CSV and use Excel to filter only Edit.

```
GetUserAccessReport "http://site" > "c:\path\permision_report.csv"
```

You can download script from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SharePoint-Access-Report-ac5e8235

**Script**

```
#Script written and modified by Adnan Amin
#Blog: http://mstechtalk.com
#twitter: @adnan_amin
#facebook: https://www.facebook.com/groups/SharePoint.Pakistan/
#facebook: https://www.facebook.com/MSTechTalk
#The initial idea was taken from another technet gallery script by Salaudeen Rajack at https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Permission-2840f327
#Script written by Salaudeen only genrate report for a single person, where as below script generates acceess permissions details for all users.

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Function GetUserAccessReport($WebAppURL, $FileUrl)
{
 #Get All Site Collections of the WebApp
 $SiteCollections = Get-SPSite -WebApplication $WebAppURL -Limit All

#Write CSV- TAB Separated File) Header
"URL `t Site/List `t Title `t PermissionType `t Permissions  `t LoginName" | out-file $FileUrl


    #Check Web Application Policies
    $WebApp= Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL

    foreach ($Policy in $WebApp.Policies) 
    {
        #Check if the search users is member of the group
        #if($Policy.UserName -eq $SearchUser)
          # {
                #Write-Host $Policy.UserName
                $PolicyRoles=@()
                foreach($Role in $Policy.PolicyRoleBindings)
                {
                    $PolicyRoles+= $Role.Name +";"
                }
                #Write-Host "Permissions: " $PolicyRoles

                "$($AdminWebApp.URL) `t Web Application `t $($AdminSite.Title)`t  Web Application Policy `t $($PolicyRoles) `t $($Policy.UserName)" | Out-File $FileUrl -Append
            #}
     }

  #Loop through all site collections
   foreach($Site in $SiteCollections) 
    {
      #Check Whether the Search User is a Site Collection Administrator
      foreach($SiteCollAdmin in $Site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators)
        {
                "$($Site.RootWeb.Url) `t Site `t $($Site.RootWeb.Title)`t Site Collection Administrator `t Site Collection Administrator `t $($SiteCollAdmin.LoginName)" | Out-File $FileUrl -Append

        }

       #Loop throuh all Sub Sites
       foreach($Web in $Site.AllWebs) 
       {    
            if($Web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True)
                {
                #Get all the users granted permissions to the list
                foreach($WebRoleAssignment in $Web.RoleAssignments ) 
                    { 
                      #Is it a User Account?
                        if($WebRoleAssignment.Member.userlogin)    
                            {
                                        #Get the Permissions assigned to user
                                        $WebUserPermissions=@()
                                        foreach ($RoleDefinition  in $WebRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                                        {
                                            $WebUserPermissions += $RoleDefinition.Name +";"
                                        }
                                        #write-host "with these permissions: " $WebUserPermissions
                                        #Send the Data to Log file
                                        "$($Web.Url) `t Site `t $($Web.Title)`t Direct Permission `t $($WebUserPermissions)  `t $($WebRoleAssignment.Member.LoginName)" | Out-File $FileUrl -Append
                            }
                    #Its a SharePoint Group, So search inside the group and check if the user is member of that group
                    else  
                        {
                        foreach($user in $WebRoleAssignment.member.users)
                            {
                                    #Get the Group's Permissions on site
                                    $WebGroupPermissions=@()
                                    foreach ($RoleDefinition  in $WebRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                                    {
                                        $WebGroupPermissions += $RoleDefinition.Name +";"
                                    }
                                    #write-host "Group has these permissions: " $WebGroupPermissions

                                    #Send the Data to Log file
                                    "$($Web.Url) `t Site `t $($Web.Title)`t Member of $($WebRoleAssignment.Member.Name) Group `t $($WebGroupPermissions) `t $($user.LoginName)" | Out-File $FileUrl -Append
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                #********  Check Lists with Unique Permissions ********/
                    foreach($List in $Web.lists)
                    {
                        if($List.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True -and ($List.Hidden -eq $false))
                        {
                           #Get all the users granted permissions to the list
                            foreach($ListRoleAssignment in $List.RoleAssignments ) 
                                { 
                                  #Is it a User Account?
                                    if($ListRoleAssignment.Member.userlogin)    
                                        {

                                                    #Get the Permissions assigned to user
                                                    $ListUserPermissions=@()
                                                    foreach ($RoleDefinition  in $ListRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                                                    {
                                                        $ListUserPermissions += $RoleDefinition.Name +";"
                                                    }
                                                    #write-host "with these permissions: " $ListUserPermissions

                                                    #Send the Data to Log file
                                                    "$($List.ParentWeb.Url)/$($List.RootFolder.Url) `t List `t $($List.Title)`t Direct Permission1 `t $($ListUserPermissions)  `t $($ListRoleAssignment.Member)" | Out-File $FileUrl -Append
                                        }
                                        #Its a SharePoint Group, So search inside the group and check if the user is member of that group
                                    else  
                                        {
                                            foreach($user in $ListRoleAssignment.member.users)
                                                {
                                                        #Get the Group's Permissions on site
                                                        $ListGroupPermissions=@()
                                                        foreach ($RoleDefinition  in $ListRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                                                        {
                                                            $ListGroupPermissions += $RoleDefinition.Name +";"
                                                        }
                                                        #write-host "Group has these permissions: " $ListGroupPermissions

                                                        #Send the Data to Log file
                                                        "$($Web.Url) `t List `t $($List.Title)`t Member of $($ListRoleAssignment.Member.Name) Group `t $($user.LoginName) `t $($user.LoginName)" | Out-File $FileUrl -Append

                                                }
                                    }   
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }   
            }

        }
```

Comment: will this get users from an AD group?

Answer (score 1):

You can get  Permission reports by User wise include who has edit permission you can filter out from that

```
> function Get-SPPermissionsReport($web, $recursive) {   $web |
> Get-SPUser | % { New-Object PSObject -Property @{
>     UserLogin = $_.UserLogin
>     'Roles given explicitly' = $_.Roles
>     'Roles given via groups' = $_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}
>     Groups = $_.Groups
>     Url = $web.Url
>     }   }   if($recursive) { $web.Webs | % { Get-SPPermissionsReport $_ $recursive } } } $web = Get-SPWeb
> http://yoursharepoint/sites/department Get-SPPermissionsReport $web
> $true | Sort-Object UserLogin | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code it will list Roles that start with Edit.If you know the Role then rhis code can be helpful.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://spe131:5664/")
$groups = $site.RootWeb.sitegroups
foreach ($grp in $groups) 
{
        "Group: " + $grp.Roles; 
        if( $grp.Roles -like 'Edit*'){
            foreach ($user in $grp.users) 
            {
                "  User: " + $user.name
            } 
        }
        else{
            "false"
        }
}
$site.Dispose()
```

Please inform me if it help.

Thanks